# NetCDF file apply conditions for each year and each gridpoint of daily data

Tags: python, datagrid, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF file with daily mean temperature values, with gridsize 14*16 (about 240 grid points), for 60 years (2031-2090). I want for each grid point and for each period April-September per year to calculate the k variable conditionally, exactly as the following command:

```
#for each year (Apr-Sep) and for each gridpoint, k is the sum as following:

    if (((tas - 10) >= 0) & (tas < 15)):
        k = k + tas
        
    elif(((tas - 10) >= 0) & (tas > 15)):
        k = k + 15
        
    elif(((tas - 10) < 0)):
        k = k + 0
```

So I suppose, that the k will be an array with 60 rows (1 for each year-period) and one value per grid point. I want this array to be exported as a NetCDF at the end. I found this process really complicated as I am new to Python.

tas variable is the value of the daily mean temperature. K will be the sum of each year/period for each gridpoint, according to the conditions.

I think I have to work with xarray, I read the file with xarray but I struggle to build the code with the conditions for each grid and period per year.

Thank you so much in advance.

[here is a print of my NetCDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0NF.png)
[here is a sample of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbH37.png)

Comment: I feel like there are two questions here. Are you asking about the algorithm to calculate k or are you asking how to write netCDF output with xarray? Maybe you can share what you have coded so far?

Comment: You are right, there are 2 questions. Sorry for this. My main issue is to calculate k for each grid point and for each period per year (my data are daily), then I will try to create the output NetCDF file. So let's try for the first.